# AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute '_built' in python

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to predict from my own saved model. The model was save using .pickel file. And also I'm using keras.preprocessing for importing image. My code works fine with jupyter nootbook as .ipynb file, but when tried to run this same code (without jupyter nootbook) with .py file in CMD using same environment, than I faced this problem...

```
import pickle
with open ('test.pckle', 'rb') as f:
    model = pickle.load(f)
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import cv2
import os
from keras.preprocessing import image
import sys

img = image.img_to_array(pic)
X = np.array(img)
ina = X.astype('float32')
tra = ina / 255.
roi_X = np.expand_dims(tra, axis=0)
predictions = model.predict(roi_X)[0]

Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "....\GuiExe.py", line 317, in <module>
    pba = Application()
  File "C:\..\GuiExe.py", line 64, in __init__
    self.take_snapshot()
  File "C:\...\GuiExe.py", line 231, in take_snapshot
    predictions = model.predict(roi_X)[0]
  File "C:\...\.conda\envs\tensor2\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1147, in predict
    x, _, _ = self._standardize_user_data(x)
  File "C:\...\.conda\envs\tensor2\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 644, in _standardize_user_data
    if not self.built:
  File "C:\....\.conda\envs\tensor2\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 191, in built
    return self._built
AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute '_built'
```

I have two environments in my anaconda3 navigator, one with python 3.6, tensorflow 1.15, & keras 2.31, other one with python 3.5, tensorflow 1.10, & keras 2.2.2

Both the environments shows same error.

Comment: Are you sure you're actually unpickling the same file, from Jupyter and command line? (Try specifying and absolute path to `test.pckle`.) It's a bit of an odd problem, and the information you show might not be enough to answer.

Comment: @Caesar,  yes, I'm unpickling the same file, and I also tried  specify and give absolute path to `test.pckle` . But nothing changed.  Please tell me how can I give more information, or Which ones information should I provide, to get a solution. Please help.
Thanks in advance.